# When a familiar delivers a Touch spell, who should be Helped?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, helping

Picture this situation. Myself and a friend are a pair of casters, both with familiars. My friend's familiar has just gotten in position next to an enemy we're fighting, and I know he intends to use his upcoming action to have the familiar deliver a touch range attack spell (such as Shocking Grasp), per Find Familiar...

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll.

My familiar's turn comes up, but I won't need its help when it's my turn for whatever reason. Instead, I want it to use the Help action to help my friend's spell land, so I order it to move next to...

...who? The caster, or the familiar?

Comment: Does the linked question ask the same thing you are asking and give you an answer? If not, please [edit] and explain how the questions are different.

Comment: This is not a duplicate; the other question *might* answer it, but this is not *the same question*. Furthermore, there has yet to be a definitive answer to the other one, leaving this one unanswered as well. Additionally, for one of the potential answers to the other question, this question *would not be resolved*.

Comment: @Ifusaso can you explain a bit more where you see the differences? To me, they both seem to be asking "who is the target of the help action?". Am I missing something? Also note, that having a conclusive answer is not necessary for duplicating. If anything it is more important to keep all the conversation in one place in such cases then when an answer is settled.

Comment: Setting aside whether or not it's a duplicate, or who's doing the "attacking" when a familiar delivers the spell (a valid question)... "Instead, I want it to use the Help action to help my friend's spell land, so I order it to move next to... ...who? The caster, or the familiar?" - The Help action (when helping with an attack) requires you to be within 5 feet of the target being attacked, not the attacker.

Comment: The other question is a general "how does the Help mechanic work" whereas this one is specifically about a caster interacting with their Familiar's ability to deliver touch spells. In this case, the caster could be nowhere near (up to 100ft) the melee. This *could* be an exception to the other rule if the answer is 'near the caster'.